# MDADM RAID-0 does not increased size after grow on AWS Linux with EBS

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm, raid-0

I wanted to grew a Raid0 from 2 disks to 3 (each 1TB EBS on Amazon AWS) but the size did not change thereafter. The RAID started with two disks sdc and sdd and the new one was sdf.

Here is the grow-command:

```
sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=3 --add /dev/xvdf
```

after some hours mdstats showed the following info (using `cat /proc/mdstat`):

```
Personalities : [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid0 xvdf[3] xvdd[1] xvdc[0]
  3221223936 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
```

so I hoped it worked but `df -h` gave me:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0        2.0T  1.6T  297G  85% /mnt/md0
```

and `sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0` showed:

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Jul 22 16:05:40 2014
     Raid Level : raid0
     Array Size : 3221223936 (3072.00 GiB 3298.53 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sun Sep  7 01:37:39 2014
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Chunk Size : 512K

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0     202       32        0      active sync   /dev/sdc
   1     202       48        1      active sync   /dev/sdd
   3     202       80        2      active sync   /dev/sdf
```

so the RAID seem to have 3 devices and the correct size (3072 GB) but `df` does not show this. Strangely, the new disk (sdf) is listed as number 3 and number 2 is not listed.

Note: I did use a "blank" EBS without any formatting - should new RAID disks be formatted before added to a (already formatted) RAID?

What am I missing? Do I have to (partially) format the new RAID disk (there is still data on the RAID I need (but I have a Backup))? Is `df` misreading the RAID or is the RAID grow not finished yet?

Comment: Could you please tell me what AMI-id/region you got this working on? I've been trying this for a couple weeks and I could only get it to work on ArchLinux.

Comment: The region should'nt be important. But I use AmazonLinux, Ubuntu or Debian.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your steps didn't mention expanding the actual filesystem that lives on /dev/md0. You expand the RAID (which is the 'physical' disk) and then you need to expand the filesystem (ext4 or the like) on top of that to make `df` see it.

Comment: I formated the original RAID with 2 disks using `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0`. How can I change/expand the file system of the third disk (without formating the whole RAID)?

Comment: Thanks for the idea: After Googleing a bit about the file system I noticed that I only have to resize the filesystem using the command `resize2fs /dev/md0`